# Is it a good practice to log line number in error code to the user?

Tags: java, logging, error-logging

I have been tasked with logging the line number as part of the error code shown to the user. Currently I am using:

```
StackTraceElement[] stackTraceElement = e.getStackTrace();
lineNumber = stackTraceElement[0].getLineNumber();
```

I know that the above approach may fail depending on the JVM version.
Also, I have seen the [`PatternLayout`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/PatternLayout.html) where it is mentioned that "Generating caller location information is extremely slow. Its use should be avoided unless execution speed is not an issue.".

Since this message will be presented to the user, should I still log the line number as part of the error code? I am trying to understand the pros and cons of this approach. Also, does the *log4j* warning apply only to its own implementation or rather is it a warning against location information generally?

Comment: Code compiled with debug information will already have a line number in the stack trace.  Are you sure your code does not already have this information?

Comment: Generally its better if your program doesn't give errors, and can receive all input. This will make it more user friendly. If your program does give errors, it will not be helpfull for the user to know the line number. You however will want to know the line number, so you should make it display a message of some sort that tells the user to email you the stack trace when the error occurs

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Yes it does in the stacktrace. What I am trying to do is take this stracktrace and extract the line number and then display it to the user as error code. so when the user calls, I will know the exact line number where it occurred.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, generally speaking your program should report two kind of errors:

1. The errors that are for the user (when the user is not doing what is expected from him), which should actually be better called "feedback" to help him feed your program with the right data (that's good UX practice).
2. The errors that are generated because of a bug, which are actually not targeted at the user, but at *you* the developer, sadly through the user. Then yes, it might be a good idea to log line numbers (or give your errors unique names/identifiers so that you can trace easily where it's been sent from). But a better idea is to then use a framework to report such issues directly to you through Internet (good practice being to ask for permission first).

Answer (score 1):

What you should show to the user is what went wrong and what he can do about it, if anything. The line number information needs to be available, e.g. via a 'More details' button, in case he needs to raise a support ticket, but you don't want to frighten him or confuse him with it up front. Just look at how many stack traces get misread or indeed ignored completely here, and this community is supposed to be computer programmers.

Comment: Thanks. As I mentioned in the comment, what I am trying to do is take this stracktrace and extract the line number and then display it to the user as error code. so when the user calls, I will know the exact line number where it occurred. So, other than the user experience, is it ok to get the location information for this purpose? I was concerned about the warning in the log4j link

Comment: well, have you got only one class in your code? And can you be sure you'll always have one class in the unforeseeable future? I bet not, so using line number is not a unique reference to your error.

Comment: The warning is about performance. You've just had an error, and you're about to show a message to the user, and he is about to stop and read it. You don't care about performance at this point. But I agree with @zmo. A line number by itself is not adequate, and a line number plus a class name is starting to get intimidating. Maybe you should just show an error number of your own devising.

Comment: @zmo: Agreed. Plan was to assign unique codes to each of the file and concatenate the line number. I have less than 999 files and line number does not exceed 4 digits. so it would be a 7 digit code

Comment: @Raghav as a rule, when designing something: *Keep It Simple, Stupid!* ;-) it is always a better idea to give a nice gentle error, log the full stack trace (with all line numbers etc) and get it sent to you by the user (either through one click, or copy paste in a mail). The more data you get on an error, the better you'll be able to debug. A simple error code won't give you any context on how to reproduce the bug and when it happened!

Answer (score 1):

Generally its better if your program doesn't give errors, and can receive all input, and give you tips on how to use the application. This will give users a much better experience if you want them to buy your product, etc.. If your program does give errors, it will not be helpful for the user to know the line number. You however will want to know the line number, so you should make it display a message of some sort that tells the user to email you the stack trace when the error occurs. Or you could have it report the error message automatically and email it to you.

Sorry, I'm a bit late I was unclear what the question was asking, so I posted this as a comment, but clearly it is an acceptable answer.